# interval in dataframe to start from the first row [python 3.6.0]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Below data is in the interval of 5 mins, trying to group it in 10 mins

Dataframe names as `df`:

| script_id | date_time | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 10:45:00 | 1492.9 | 1493.85 | 1492.15 | 1492.9 | 7189 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 10:50:00 | 1492.9 | 1495.95 | 1492.2 | 1495.85 | 15440 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 10:55:00 | 1495.85 | 1495.95 | 1494 | 1494.5 | 8360 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 11:00:00 | 1494.5 | 1494.5 | 1492 | 1492.05 | 9910 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 11:05:00 | 1492.05 | 1493.9 | 1492 | 1493.35 | 14961 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 11:10:00 | 1493.4 | 1493.4 | 1488 | 1489.25 | 16493 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 11:15:00 | 1489.25 | 1492 | 1489.25 | 1490.6 | 14590 |
| 201 | 2019-01-01 11:20:00 | 1490.6 | 1491.65 | 1490 | 1491.5 | 3470 |

While executing the below code:

```
df_f = df.groupby(['script_id', pd.Grouper(key='date_time', freq=f'{tf}T')])\
                            .agg(open=pd.NamedAgg(column='open', aggfunc='first'),
                                high=pd.NamedAgg(column='high', aggfunc='max'),
                                low=pd.NamedAgg(column='low', aggfunc='min'),
                                close=pd.NamedAgg(column='close', aggfunc='last'),
                                volume=pd.NamedAgg(column='volume', aggfunc='sum'))\
                                .reset_index()
                print(df_f)
```

The result is (have removed unwanted details from here):

| date_time |
| --- |
| 2019-01-01 10:40:00 |
| 2019-01-01 10:50:00 |
| 2019-01-01 11:00:00 |
| 2019-01-01 11:10:00 |

---

But it should be (have removed unwanted details from here):- **(Expected Result)**

| date_time |
| --- |
| 2019-01-01 10:45:00 |
| 2019-01-01 10:55:00 |
| 2019-01-01 11:05:00 |
| 2019-01-01 11:15:00 |

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just need to supply the offset argument when you call `pd.Grouper(... offset="5T")`

```
df_f = df.groupby(['script_id', pd.Grouper(key='date_time', freq='10T', offset="5T")])\
                            .agg(open=pd.NamedAgg(column='open', aggfunc='first'),
                                high=pd.NamedAgg(column='high', aggfunc='max'),
                                low=pd.NamedAgg(column='low', aggfunc='min'),
                                close=pd.NamedAgg(column='close', aggfunc='last'),
                                volume=pd.NamedAgg(column='volume', aggfunc='sum'))\
                                .reset_index()

print(df_f)
   script_id           date_time     open     high      low    close  volume
0        201 2019-01-01 10:45:00  1492.90  1495.95  1492.15  1495.85   22629
1        201 2019-01-01 10:55:00  1495.85  1495.95  1492.00  1492.05   18270
2        201 2019-01-01 11:05:00  1492.05  1493.90  1488.00  1489.25   31454
3        201 2019-01-01 11:15:00  1489.25  1492.00  1489.25  1491.50   18060
```

---

Older versions of `pandas.Grouper` objects use `base` instead of `offset`. `pd.Grouper(..., base=5)`

```
>>> df_f = df.groupby(['script_id', pd.Grouper(key='date_time', freq=f'10T', base=5)])\
                            .agg(open=pd.NamedAgg(column='open', aggfunc='first'),
                                high=pd.NamedAgg(column='high', aggfunc='max'),
                                low=pd.NamedAgg(column='low', aggfunc='min'),
                                close=pd.NamedAgg(column='close', aggfunc='last'),
                                volume=pd.NamedAgg(column='volume', aggfunc='sum'))\
                                .reset_index()

print(df_f)
   script_id           date_time     open     high      low    close  volume
0        201 2019-01-01 10:45:00  1492.90  1495.95  1492.15  1495.85   22629
1        201 2019-01-01 10:55:00  1495.85  1495.95  1492.00  1492.05   18270
2        201 2019-01-01 11:05:00  1492.05  1493.90  1488.00  1489.25   31454
3        201 2019-01-01 11:15:00  1489.25  1492.00  1489.25  1491.50   18060
```

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offset'`

Comment: older versions of pandas use the `base` argument instead of `offset`. Try `pd.Grouper(... base=5)` I'll edit my answer as well

Comment: `base` is not working when time is from 10:50 to 11:25. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obfou.png)

Comment: What about that result isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `origin='start'` in `pd.Grouper` to take the first value as reference:

```
tf = 10
(df.groupby(['script_id', pd.Grouper(key='date_time', freq=f'{tf}T', origin='start')])
   .agg(open=pd.NamedAgg(column='open', aggfunc='first'),
        high=pd.NamedAgg(column='high', aggfunc='max'),
        low=pd.NamedAgg(column='low', aggfunc='min'),
        close=pd.NamedAgg(column='close', aggfunc='last'),
        volume=pd.NamedAgg(column='volume', aggfunc='sum'))
   .reset_index()
)
```

*NB. I reworked your code as pipeline which, IMO, is easier to follow*

output:

```
   script_id           date_time     open     high      low    close  volume
0        201 2019-01-01 10:45:00  1492.90  1495.95  1492.15  1495.85   22629
1        201 2019-01-01 10:55:00  1495.85  1495.95  1492.00  1492.05   18270
2        201 2019-01-01 11:05:00  1492.05  1493.90  1488.00  1489.25   31454
3        201 2019-01-01 11:15:00  1489.25  1492.00  1489.25  1491.50   18060
```

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'origin'`

Comment: @Kabomi what is `pd.__version__`?

Comment: Version is *0.25.3*

Comment: In this version the equivalent of `origin` is `base` (see [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) doc v0.25). This should be an int. Can you try `base=5`?

Comment: Agreed, but there is one extra row [10:35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaMO0.png)

Comment: and with `base=45`?

Comment: The base will not always be 45, like first time will not be x:45 always

Comment: Well, sorry I've not been using pandas 0.25 for a while now. Can't you upgrade?

Comment: Other option, if the extra row is consistent, you can group and drop the first row

Comment: you mean degrade, and I think that will impact other modules like pandasql & ta-lib. And `drop` will also not work as if you see row 2 (index 1) the high is incorrect. so looks like `base` not working as expected

Comment: I meant **up**grade, the current version (with functional `origin`) is pandas 1.3, lots of nice new features and bug fixes worth the upgrade ;)

Comment: I tried [pip install pandas --upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1oTq.png) and it says already satisfied

Comment: maybe you have several python/pandas versions on your machine. What does `pip show pandas` say?

Comment: [here are the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjTuR.png) Ahh, may be it will not work in python **3.6**?