# Upgrade pandas 0.25.3 to 1.3.2

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I currently having pandas 0.25.3, was trying to upgrade it to latest version:

`pip install --upgrade pandas` , `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` (used both) but it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\python\lib\site-packages
> (0.25.3) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in
> c:\python\lib\site-packages (fro m pandas) (1.19.5) Requirement
> already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from
> pandas) (2019.1) Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1
> in c:\python\lib\site-pack ages (from pandas) (2.8.1) Requirement
> already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyt
> hon-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)

Then I tried:

`pip install --upgrade pandas 1.3.1` , `pip3 install --upgrade pandas 1.3.1` (used both) but it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\python\lib\site-packages
> (0.25.3) ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement 1.3.1 (from versi ons: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for 1.3.1

Third try as per the comment:

`pip install --upgrade pandas==1.3.1` , `pip3 install --upgrade pandas==1.3.1` (used both) but it says:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> pandas== (from ve rsions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2,
> 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.
> 4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.
> 9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15 .0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19 .0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23 .0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25 .2, 0.25.3) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==

Comment: Use the `==` like so: `pip install pandas==1.3.1` or just `pip install -U pandas`

Comment: @StefanFalk tried that as well, but it still shows error.

Comment: What Python version are you using then?

Comment: You need python 3.7.1 or newer to install python 1.3.2. [python version support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#python-version-support)

Comment: currently I am using python 3.6.0

Comment: Well then that explains why you cannot install the pandas version you're looking for.

Comment: @Kabomi if this is related to your previous question version 1.1 should work

Comment: hmm, the reason I was looking to update the pandas because of this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951354/interval-in-dataframe-to-start-from-the-first-row-python-3-6-0#comment121858340_68951686)

Comment: @mozway I guess 1.1 is also not available for python 3.6

Comment: will python 3.7 work with windows 7 32bit (reason i am asking that i want all the testings to be done in my old PC)

Comment: I have not used it myself, but [there is an installer on the website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/). No reason to assume that it does not work

Comment: lol it says, atleast windows 8

Answer (score 1):

From the [pandas's Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.3.1/), you can see that the version `pandas==1.3.1` requires Python >= 3.7.1.

[image]

In order to use this version of pandas, you need to upgrade Python. However, if you wish to keep Python 3.6, you can only upgrade pandas to the latest available version for Python 3.6 which is `pandas==1.1.5` (see [1.1.5](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.1.5/))